# rails acts_as_paranoid updated_at column on destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-paranoid

Is there a way to update the `updated_at` column when calling the `destroy` method using acts_as_paranoid gem?

When I call `destroy`, the `deleted_at` column is set but the `updated_at` column is not.

Comment: check if this helps https://github.com/ActsAsParanoid/acts_as_paranoid#callbacks

Comment: thank you very much ! I figured out the solution

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to do this in general.

In the model I added this line of code:

```rb
before_destroy :touch
```